Какие бы ответы вы выбрали в данном задании?
На расссвете мы с Лёнькой напились чаю и пошли на мшары искать глухарей. (2)Идти было скучно.
– (3)Ты бы, Лёня, рассказал чего-нибудь повеселей.
– (4)Чего рассказывать?  — ответил Лёнька.  — (5)Разве про старушек в нашей деревне. (6)Старушки эти  — дочери знаменитейшего художника Пожалостина. (7)Академик он был, а вышел из наших пастушат, из сопливых. (8)Его гравюры висят в музеях в Париже, Лондоне и у нас в Рязани. (9)Небось видели?
(10)Я вспомнил прекрасные, чуть пожелтевшие от времени гравюры на стенах своей комнаты в доме у двух хлопотливых старух. (11)Вспомнилось мне и первое, очень странное ощущение от гравюр. (12)То были портреты старомодных людей, и я никак не мог избавиться от их взглядов. (13)Толпа дам и мужчин в наглухо застёгнутых сюртуках, толпа семидесятых годов девятнадцатого столетия, смотрела на меня со стен с глубоким вниманием.
– (14)Приходит как-то в сельсовет кузнец Егор,  — продолжил Лёня.  — (15)Нечем, говорит, чинить то, что требуется, потому давайте колокола снимать.
(16)Встревает тут Федосья, баба из Пу́стыни: (17)«У Пожалостиных в доме старухи по медным доскам ходят. (18)Что-то на тех досках нацарапано  — не пойму. (19)Эти доски и пригодятся».
(20)Я пришёл к Пожалостиным, сказал, в чём дело, и попросил эти доски показать. (21)Старушка выносит доски, завёрнутые в чистый рушник. (22)Я взглянул и замер. (23)Мать честна́я, до чего тонкая работа, до чего твёрдо вырезано! (24)Особенно портрет Пугачёва  — глядеть долго нельзя: кажется, с ним самим разговариваешь. (25)«Давайте мне доски на хранение, иначе их на гвозди переплавят»,  — говорю ей.
(26)3аплакала она и говорит: (27)«Что вы! (28)Это народная ценность, я их ни за что не отдам».
(29)В общем, спасли мы эти доски  — отправили в Рязань, в музей.
(30)Потом созвали собрание, чтобы меня судить за то, что доски спрятал. (31)Я вышел и говорю: (32)«Не вы, а ваши дети поймут ценность этих гравюр, а труд чужой почитать надо. (33)Человек вышел из пастухов, десятки лет учился на чёрном хлебе и воде, в каждую доску столько труда вложено, бессонных ночей, мучений человеческих, таланта...»
– (34)Таланта!  — повторил Лёня громче.  — (35)Это понимать надо! (36)Это беречь и ценить надо! (37)Ведь правда?
 
Какие из высказываний соответствуют содержанию текста? Укажите номера ответов.

Знаменитый художник Пожалостин, гравюры которого висят в музеях Парижа, Лондона и в Рязани, был выходцем из рязанских пастушат.
На гравюрах, висевших в доме дочерей Пожалостина, были изображены современники рассказчика – люди двадцатого столетия.
Особенно поразил рассказчика портрет Пугачёва, показанный старушкой.
Старушка не отдала Лёньке гравюры, потому что считала, что они принадлежат только ей.
Старушка понимала художественную ценность досок, воспринимая творчество отца как настоящее искусство.

Задание из огэ, но на официальных сайтах почему-то конкретно эти вопросы не смог найти. Везде, где я смотрел, в ответе выбирают вариант 3,хотя портрет Пугачёва понравился Лëньке, а не рассказчику, и поэтому утверждение неверное. Может я чего-то не понимаю? Заранее спасибо за помощь

_«3)Ты бы, Лёня, рассказал чего-нибудь повеселей.
– (4)Чего рассказывать?  — ответил Лёнька.  — (5)Разве про старушек в нашей деревне…»_ === И дальше Лёнька начал свой рассказ. Он, видимо, и считается рассказчиком в этом задании.

Весь рассказ ведётся не от лица Лëньки, то есть по логике рассказчик другой человек

Думаю, Вы правы в своих сомнениях. Я лишь высказал своё предположение, почему в ответе может выбираться и вариант (3). Моё мнение – задание составлено некорректно, коль позволяет неоднозначно понимать, кого именно составители задания назвали рассказчиком.

Какие бы ответы вы выбрали в данном задании?
15
Почему?

Знаменитый художник Пожалостин, гравюры которого висят в музеях
Парижа, Лондона и в Рязани, был выходцем из рязанских пастушат.


Пожалостин был академиком и вышел из рязанских пастухов (см. 7). ДА.


На гравюрах, висевших в доме дочерей Пожалостина, были изображены
современники рассказчика – люди двадцатого столетия.


На гравюрах была изображена "толпа семидесятых годов девятнадцатого столетия" (см. 13). НЕТ.


Особенно поразил рассказчика портрет Пугачёва, показанный старушкой.


Портрет Пугачёва поразил Лёньку, а не рассказчика (см. 22-24). НЕТ.


Старушка не отдала Лёньке гравюры, потому что считала, что они
принадлежат только ей.


Она не хотела отдавать гравюры, потому что считала, что они — народное достояние (см. 26-28). НЕТ.


Старушка понимала художественную ценность досок, воспринимая
творчество отца как настоящее искусство.


Старушка считала доски "народной ценностью", что указывает на её понимание художественной ценности (см. 26-28). ДА.

Пара слов о ваших рассуждениях
Почему вы доверяете неофициальным источникам? В них могут написать что угодно.
